# I can't access the data inside one file/store

Tags: vuejs3, webstorm, pinia

I hade made two Pinia stores in my projects and my stores finished work. Before when the pinia was created first automatically all work good. You can see that WebStorm don't see STEP property. I don't know where is problem- in Pinia and Vue or in WebStorm. I will glad to heard any variants for solve that.

[image]

Below you can see my first store and it works well, but I don't see property in my Idea too.

[image]

I have tried updating WebStorm, but it doesn't get correct result. Maybe someone know what happened?

In those examples I'm trying to get access to `step` property and `users`.